# Json parsing error for specific string

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

Simple question:

Here is my string:

```
{Path:5984fcb4-8bf8-4205-86f8-e6e2042ba610.jpg,StatusCode:OK}
```

Why can't I parse my string to Json using the following method:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

This [site](http://jsonlint.com/) says also my json is not in a correct format.

What do I have to do to transfer this kind of data in json format?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: These doesn't work too: {Path: "37028c2a-362d-49a5-9c59-f13c1188f9e7.jpg", StatusCode: "OK"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string needs to look like this:

```
{"Path":"5984fcb4-8bf8-4205-86f8-e6e2042ba610.jpg","StatusCode":"OK"}
```

You might also need single quotes around that:

```
'{"Path":"5984fcb4-8bf8-4205-86f8-e6e2042ba610.jpg","StatusCode":"OK"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not proper, needs quotes around keys and values for proper json

```
{"Path":"5984fcb4-8bf8-4205-86f8-e6e2042ba610.jpg","StatusCode":"OK"}
```